# What is a Ref in Git?

Tags: git

The error I received in attempting to push suggests that I consult the  ‘Note about fast-forwards’ in ‘git push --help’

This note contains the paragraph

> When an update changes a branch (or more in general, a ref) that used to point at commit A to point at another commit B, it is called a fast-forward update if and only if B is a descendant of A.

I am guessing that "an update" means changes to the code that I have made and that these changes would be in my current branch ( thus I have a changed branch)  but what does it meant by the "(or more in general, a ref)" ?

I can't find the word "ref" in [this glossary](https://www.atlassian.com/git/glossary/terminology)

I can see a folder called "refs" inside my .git directory

What is a ref?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References (found by searching for `ref`: https://git-scm.com/search/results?search=ref )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [the actual Git glossary](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_ref) instead:

> A name that begins with `refs/` (e.g. `refs/heads/master`) that points to an [object name](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_object_name) or another ref ...

Note that branch names, like `master`, are simply refs (references) that start with `refs/heads/`.  Tags all start with `refs/tags/`.  So *reference* is a generalized form that covers branch names, tag names, and more names.

> I am guessing that "an update" means changes to **the code** that I have made ...

(emphasis mine)

No: the idea here is that a reference like a branch name contains a *commit hash*; what's being updated is the contained hash.  If `refs/heads/master` contains, e.g., the ID `932b573406fda922d8edbecb0d7f9ad3ce9155ec` right now, and you ask Git to update it to contain `d35688db19c9ea97e9e2ce751dc7b47aee21636b` instead, Git can check to see whether commit `932b573406fda922d8edbecb0d7f9ad3ce9155ec` is an ancestor of commit `d35688db19c9ea97e9e2ce751dc7b47aee21636b`.  If so, this update is a fast-forward.

Each commit is a pure snapshot.  Git does not compare commit snapshot contents unless and until you ask it to do so.  Most of the time, it looks instead at the commit *graph*, which is formed by connecting each commit node (identified by its hash ID) to its parent node(s) (identified by their hash IDs).

Comment: Is a hash ID the same as the SHA-1 which is also called the object name?

Comment: Is "pointing to" as in pointing to an object name" the same as "contains" as in "the contained hash" ?

Comment: @kirsteng: yes. If master resolves to d35688db... we say that it "points to" that commit.

Answer (score 5):

A Ref is Git's mechanism to represent a branch, an id of an object (also called object name), a tag, etc. and even another ref (which is called symbolic ref)

Source:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/refs-and-the-reflog
https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary

Comment: So, a ref is a variable name, and `/` is allowed to be part of that name. Would that be right?